# Add parameters to NFS mount

Tags: linux, networking, boot, nfs, root-filesystem

I try to start Android on device via `NFS` and `TFTP`. Everything goes good until Android system starts booting. Something happens with network parameters and connection falls and boot freezes

```
[   60.881134] nfs: server 128.247.77.158 not responding, still trying
```

I've decided to try add parameter to mount command such as [bg, intr and hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29197). Is it possible to configure this parameters before system boot? Or should I modify flags in kernel code (somewhere [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/do_mounts.c))?

Comment: Does your Android device know how to get to `128.247.77.158`?

Comment: @roaima, yes it does. First of all my device downloads `u-boot` via `TFTP` from host. Then mounts `rootfs` and starts to boot Android. Host has the same address `128.247.77.158` all the time. Wired that there is only one log about connection loose. System do nothing after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem. 
When Android starts it makes flush of all rules. The code that does this work I found in file `system/netd/RouteController.cpp` function `int flushRules()`. When I have blocked execution of code of this function I haven't seen message about NFS connection loose anymore.

```
// Returns 0 on success or negative errno on failure.
WARN_UNUSED_RESULT int flushRules() {
    return 0;//TODO workaround of NFS parameters reset 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(IP_VERSIONS); ++i) {
        const char* argv[] = {
            IP_PATH,
            IP_VERSIONS[i],
            "rule",
            "flush",
        };
        if (android_fork_execvp(ARRAY_SIZE(argv), const_cast<char**>(argv), NULL, false, false)) {
            ALOGE("failed to flush rules");
            return -EREMOTEIO;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now Android system boots with NFS as expected.